# Dateplot doesn't work if xmin/xmax are specified

Tags: pgfplots, ticks, dateplot

Here is a simple datafile `data.csv`:

```
Time,Value
"2017-01-31 12:51:05",500
"2017-01-31 12:51:05",820
"2017-01-31 13:48:14",820
"2017-01-31 13:48:14",500
```

Here is a simple plot of it:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    date coordinates in = x,
    set layers,
    every axis plot/.append style={on layer=pre main},
    xticklabel = {\hour:\minute},
    x tick label style = {align=center},
    xlabel = X, 
    ylabel = Y,
    ymin = 500.0,
    ymax = 820.0
]

\addplot [color = black, fill = black, opacity = 0.2, draw opacity = 0] table [y=Value, col sep = comma]{data.csv};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This works as you would expect:

[image]

I want to specify `xmin`, `xmax` and `xtick` (and need to add `date ZERO` apparently):

```
\begin{axis}[
    date coordinates in = x,
    set layers,
    every axis plot/.append style={on layer=pre main},
    xticklabel = {\hour:\minute},
    x tick label style = {align=center},
    date ZERO = 2017-01-31 08:00,
    xtick = {2017-01-31 09:30,2017-01-31 11:30,2017-01-31 13:30,2017-01-31 15:30},
    xmin = 2017-01-31 08:00,
    xmax = 2017-01-31 17:00,
    xlabel = X, 
    ylabel = Y,
    ymin = 500.0,
    ymax = 820.0
]
```

Now I get the following, :

```
Error: ! Dimension too large.<recently read> \pgf@xx \end{axis}
       ! Dimension too large.\pgf@process #1->{#1\global\pgf@x = \pgf@x\global \pgf@y = \pgf@y }\end{axis}
       …
```

But when I comment the `\addplot`, I get:

[image]

which is the right canvas. **Why???**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to relate to the quotes around the date/time in `data.txt`, remove those and you get

[image: output of code at bottom]

With the quotes, the `\year` somehow becomes 8215, instead of 2017. Set `xticklabel = {\year-\month-\day--\hour:\minute}, x tick label style = {align=center,rotate=45}` to see that:

[image: ticklabels with original data]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    date coordinates in = x,
    set layers,
    every axis plot/.append style={on layer=pre main},
    xticklabel = {\hour:\minute},
    x tick label style = {align=center},
    date ZERO = 2017-01-31 08:00,
    xtick = {2017-01-31 09:30,2017-01-31 11:30,2017-01-31 13:30,2017-01-31 15:30},
    xmin = 2017-01-31 08:00,
    xmax = 2017-01-31 17:00,
    xlabel = X, 
    ylabel = Y,
    ymin = 500.0,
    ymax = 820.0
]

\addplot [color = black, fill = black, opacity = 0.2, draw opacity = 0]
  table [y=Value, col sep = comma]{
Time,Value
2017-01-31 12:51:05,500
2017-01-31 12:51:05,820
2017-01-31 13:48:14,820
2017-01-31 13:48:14,500
};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Well thank you, never would have though this would be a problem. Why the hell does `dateplot` parses it properly in one case and not in the other?

Comment: @Fatalize It expects to get data of the form `yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM`, not `"yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM"`, so with incorrect input, it is perhaps no surprise that the output is incorrect.

Comment: It works when not specifying mins and max, so this is inconsistent.

Comment: @Fatalize Well, sort of works. As you can see from the part I edited into my answer, the year becomes wrong with the quotes (I can't say why), so when you specify the x-limits, the data points are actually 6200 years outside the axis limits. `xmin = 8215-01-31 08:00,  xmax = 8215-01-31 17:00` works with your original data.